# Executar OnCalcField apenas quando pressionar o [Enter]

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho um `DBGrid` que busca diversos registros gravados na tabela logo quando o formulário é aberto, este deve mostrar exatamente tudo o que tem gravado na tabela.

Existem alguns campos calculados com o evento `OnCalcFields` que logo ao abrir o formulário já retornam e mostram o valor calculado nas colunas, e isso não pode acontecer.

Pretendo que após mostrar os dados gravados na tabela, ele só efetuasse o cálculo do evento `OnCalcFields` quando o usuário clicasse em um botão, ou pressionasse a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Alguém pode dizer se tem como fazer dessa forma? Se sim poderia dar um exemplo ou uma direção de como fazer?

Comment: Coloca  no `OnKeyPress` o algoritmo que esta no `OnCalcFiends`, que so faz o calculo se for [Enter]

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, mas não funcionou, ele perde as referencias dos campos

Comment: Crie uma variável de controle no form, altere seu valor para true quando o usuário clicar no tal botão e, no OnCalcFields, inicie com "if not controle then exit;"

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro modificar o campo de Calculado para Data.
Programe no evento `KeyDown` do `DbGrid` algo como

```
begin
  if Key = VK_RETURN then
  begin
    Nome_Tabela.Edit;
    Nome_TabelaQTD.AsInteger := Nome_TabelaEVENTO.AsInteger * Nome_TabelaEVENTO2.AsInteger;
    Nome_Tabela.Post;
  end;
end;
```

Não utilizo os campos calculados exatamente por estes cenários. Já tive casos onde o processamento era gigantesco exatamente pela quantidade de registros. Neste exemplo o processamento fica resumido apenas aos casos necessários.